# connect to sqlite in android using connection string

Tags: android, sqlite

I am so new and new in android , i have a big problem with it, i create an app that needs to connect to database .so i create a database using `sqllite expert pro` as you can see  here :

```
CREATE TABLE [user](
    [name] tEXT, 
    [id] INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

My database name is `a` .i want to read the value from the user table as you can see here in my code :

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("a",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from user",null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
String username = resultSet.getString(1);
String password = resultSet.getString(2);

  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv.setText("Text is: " + username + password);
```

but it doesn't work ,should i add connection string to my code ,or should i import the database into my project,because the database is in my workspace folder.

[image]

[image]

I use this code to create a test database inside android ,but it doesn't work again?

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("ali",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TutorialsPoint(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
        mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TutorialsPoint VALUES('admin','admin');");

        Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
        resultSet.moveToFirst();
        String username = resultSet.getString(1);
        String password = resultSet.getString(2);
```

Comment: When you crete and Database in Android, it will not be in your workspace or project file, it will be on the Device that is running the application, so you need to create the table in your code, and full fill the data. I recommend read about `DatabaseHelper`, create a class to handle the Database. Or use some library like Ormlite

Comment: So you mean i should create my database using code ,is there any wizard tools that i can use it to create my database graphically ?like sqlesxpress in vs?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) its very well explained

Comment: @EhsanAkbar no, there is not graphical toll for create on Android, because the database will be created on each device but, exists libraries who help a lot, try read about Ormlite. BTW consider use the Android Studio, he have a better support from Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database needs to be copied to the phone's internal storage first. You can do it manually or with the help of this library [Android SqliteAsset Helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Follow the right method for creating database in android using codes: 
Create a class that extends `SqliteOpenHelper`.

```
    public class DbOpener extends SqliteOpenHelper {
    DbOpener(Context c){
        super(c, 1, "a", null, 1); //where "a" is the database name
    }

    public void onCreate (SqliteDatabase db){
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  TutorialsPoint (Username VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR);");
    }
}
```

Then in your activity use it as follows:

```
DbOpener opener = new DbOpener(this);

SqliteDatabase myDatabase = opener.getWritableDatabase();

//Now you can perform all your queries (including insertions) using the myDatabase object
```

Comment: thank you ,i add some details to my question ,you said i should create the database inside my code ,i did that but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change your database name to a readable one like "**mydata.db**"

Second, there is no need for connection string on using SQLite in Android like the usual ways we do with accessing database from Java code.

You need to access database by using [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Tutorial from [Android SQLite database and content provider](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). Try to get the feel with Android and SQLite from the tutorial.

Then, after you've mastering the concept and know the how, you can use your predefined database by utilizing [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/)

Comment: thank you ,i add some details to my question ,you said i should create the database inside my code ,i did that but it didn't work

Comment: Your code won't work and it's expected. What I meant is, you mingling your knowledge about database in Java for android. You need to use SQLiteOpenHelper to create and access SQLite database.

Comment: Please read and follow [Android SQLite database tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) first. Mastering the concept first and try to create a simple project based on it. After that, you can learn using your predefined database with SQLiteAssetHelper.